# IBOutlet is still nil after trying every suggestion found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have read through "all" treads here on SO, and can't manage to fix the error where my IBOutlets in a TableViewCell.xib is still nil and awakeFromNib() is never called.

### Error

```swift
productTitle.text = item?.product.description

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
 //item?.product.description is not nil
```

### What I've tried:

- Clean build folder
- Delete derived data folder
- Created a brand new Xib and .swift class from scratch (after the error first occured)
- Added `_ = self.view` in CartViewController's `viewWillAppear`
- Tried to add new labels to other XIB to check if the error occurs - it does **not**
- **In XIB, verified that :**
- Outlet are connected (done this multiple times)
- Custom class = CartProductCell
- File's owner = CartProductCell
- Reuse identifier = CartProductCell
- **In Storyboard, verified that :**
- Cell class = CartProductCell
- Reuse identifier = CartProductCell

My cell:

```swift
class CartProductCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print("awaken")
    }

    var item: orderItem? {
        didSet {

            productTitle.text = item?.product.description
        }
    }
}
```

Dequeue'ing it:

```swift
class CartViewController: UITableViewController {


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]   
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartProductCell", for: indexPath ) as! CartProductCell
        cell.item = item
        return cell

    }
}
```

Instantiating the ViewController

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    @objc func viewCart() {
        if Cart.sharedInstance.order.items.count == 0 {
            if let cartVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmptyCart") {
                let cartNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cartVC)
                self.present(cartNavigationController, animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            if let cartVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Cart") as? CartViewController {
                let cartNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cartVC)
                self.present(cartNavigationController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

- XIB are for UTTableViewCell, and it is registered by storyboard identifier
- Outlets are connected by dragging from labels to code, not in File's owner

[image: Storyboard]
[image: XIB]
[image: XIB 2]
[image: XIB 3]

Any clues?

Comment: When you say the outlets are connected in the xib, do you mean they are connected for `File's Owner`? If so, I'm pretty sure that's not the way to do it for a tableviewcell. Instead, right click the actual cell instance in your xib and connect them there. Hard to say for sure without seeing your xib contents.

Comment: How did you registered the cell?

Comment: You using XIB for the Cell right, Did you register CartProductCell to the TableView?

Comment: Updated the questions with answers and some screenshots. Appreciate the effort!

Comment: Update: I changed the registration of the cell from using storyboard to manually do it in code using `tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CartProductCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CartProductCell")` and then dequeue it using `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartProductCell", for: indexPath ) as! CartProductCell` and now it suddenly works. I'm glad, but I'd still like to understand why it didn't before. If it wasn't registered properly, it should have dumped when dequeueing, not when setting one of the properties...

Comment: You weren't using the interface version of the cell from the xib, but from the storyboard. Hence it didn't had the outlet linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was provided in comment by @Larme.

The issue was that I had a protype cell in the storyboard tableViewController and cell.XIB with the same iditifier. Hence it used the cell from the storyboard, and not the XIB where my code was.

> You weren't using the interface version of the cell from the xib, but from the storyboard. Hence it didn't had the outlet linking